# Google reCAPTCHA issue on page load

Tags: php, recaptcha

i just installed google reCPATCHA on my website and for some reason when i place the div to render the box i get the following error on the console.

It wont let me do anything, anyone any suggestions?

[image: recaptcha error]

Comment: You are going to have to post the javascript block you are using, as well as the html portion in question.

Comment: @IncredibleHat its just a simple form with an email, name and body. I do have some vuejs script but even if i comment everything out the error still persists. It will only go away if i take the div that recapcha provides out of the DOM. And the iframe that is causing the issue points to the js that google provides.

Comment: Without showing the code, it's anyones guess at this point. From the looks of it, something in your javascript is crashing javascript which in turn is causing issues down the line. Debug the code, check its syntax (all of it), and hopefully you'll spot the issue. Since we cannot do anything for you from just an image of errors.